# Polyline not complete to destination on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

i am trying to make app to enter latitude and longitude and calculate distance between to location and draw polyline between to marker location but polyline not complete drawn to other destination . this my code `

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private TextView source;
private TextView destination;
private EditText sLatitude1;
private EditText sLongtiude1;
private EditText dLatitude2;
private EditText dLongtiude2;
private Button button;
private GoogleMap mMap;
boolean mapReady = false;
MarkerOptions place1;
MarkerOptions place2;
Location location;
double lati1;
double longi1;
double lati2;
double longi2;
TextView textView;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find text that display distance
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    // find edit text and text view
    source = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourc);
    destination = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destination);
    sLatitude1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat1);
    sLongtiude1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.long1);
    dLatitude2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat2);
    dLongtiude2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.long2);
    // find button
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getDistance);
```

// here i add Polyline to Onclick

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // find string from edittext
            String lat1 = sLatitude1.getText().toString();
            // parse string to double
            lati1 = ParseDouble(lat1);
            String lon1 = sLongtiude1.getText().toString();
            longi1 = ParseDouble(lon1);
            String lat2 = dLatitude2.getText().toString();
            lati2 = ParseDouble(lat2);
            String lon2 = dLongtiude2.getText().toString();
            longi2 = ParseDouble(lon2);
            Log.i("**lat", lat2);
            CameraPosition place = CameraPosition.builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(lati1, longi1))
                    .zoom(3)
                    .bearing(6)
                    .tilt(45)
                    .build();
            flyTo(place);

            double xy1 = distanceBetween(new LatLng(lati1, longi1), new LatLng(lati2, longi2));
            String distanceis = formatNumber(xy1);
            textView.setText(distanceis);
            place1= new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati1,longi1))
                    .title("i am here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bubble_mask));
            place2= new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati2,longi2))
                    .title("my destination").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bubble_mask));



            mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                    .add(new LatLng(lati1, longi1))
                    .add(new LatLng(lati2, lati2)));
            // Add a listener for polyline clicks that changes the clicked polyline's color.
            mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                    // Flip the values of the red, green and blue components of the polyline's color.
                    polyline.setColor(polyline.getColor() ^ 0x00ffffff);
                }
            });
            mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(lati1, longi1))
                    .radius(5000)
                    .strokeColor(Color.GREEN)
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(54, 99, 255, 0)));
            mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(lati2, longi2))
                    .radius(5000)
                    .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(54, 99, 255, 0)));
            mMap.addMarker(place1);
            mMap.addMarker(place2);
        }

    });


}
  // mehtod to parse double from string

double ParseDouble(String strNumber) {
    if (strNumber != null && strNumber.length() > 0) {
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(strNumber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;   // or some value to mark this field is wrong. or make a function validates field first ...
        }
    } else return 0;
}

// get distance
public static Double distanceBetween(LatLng point1, LatLng point2) {
    if (point1 == null || point2 == null) {
        return null;
    }
    double vw = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2);
    Log.i("distance isby utillib ", String.valueOf(vw));
    return vw;
}

private String formatNumber(double distance) {
    String unit = "m";
    if (distance < 1) {
        distance *= 1000;
        unit = "mm";
    } else if (distance > 1000) {
        distance /= 1000;
        unit = "km";
    }

    return String.format("%4.3f%s", distance, unit);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapReady = true;
   mMap = googleMap;}
```

// i do not know why not complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the polyline in the wrong way!

```
 mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                    .add(new LatLng(lati1, longi1))
                    .add(new LatLng(lati2, lati2)));
```

added a point in lat2,lat2!

```
 mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                    .add(new LatLng(lati1, longi1))
                    .add(new LatLng(lati2, longi2)));
```

Comment: @N Dorigatti  thanks it done 
it behind from my eyes :(

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik you're welcome. You can accept and upvote the answer if it fixes your issue, so people will not answer again to a solved question! :+1:

Comment: I accept your answer but the system  give me notification that reputation less than 15
so  suggest me what i can do  for this.

Comment: Up vote then, and when you have rep 15 you can accept

Comment: @N Dorigatti 
now i have more than 15 reputation i accept  your answer 
i have another question  when i rotate my phone every think clean on my app i will start again from begin 
how i avoid this problem

Comment: You should add a new question for that, but you'll better to look in the documentation for saveInstanceState for Google maps